# Sending SMS using aws sns service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sms, aws-sdk

**I want to formulate a code to send the SMS to the client using AWS service i have written a code for message push and its also giving me 200 success response. But unable to get the way to send message to particular user.**

public class Amazonsms {

AWS credentials -- replace with your credentials
static String ACCESS_KEY = "AKIAIQOC7Y**********";
static String SECRET_KEY = "S2e4CwxUaZJZc***************";

```
 Sender loop
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    // Create a client
    AmazonSNSClient service = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));

    // Create a topic
    CreateTopicRequest createReq = new CreateTopicRequest()
            .withName("MyTopic");
    CreateTopicResult createRes = service.createTopic(createReq);

    for (;;) {

        // Publish to a topic
        PublishRequest publishReq = new PublishRequest()
                .withTopicArn(createRes.getTopicArn())
                .withMessage("Example notification sent at " + new Date());
        service.publish(publishReq);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-topic.html), in order to send an SMS to a topic, you need to `CreateTopic`, `Subscribe` a phone number to it (which is missing), and then `Publish` messages to each phone number subscribed to the topic. For subscribing a number to your topic you can do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
    String phoneNumber = "+1XXX5550100";
    String topicArn = createSNSTopic(snsClient);
    subscribeToTopic(snsClient, topicArn, "sms", phoneNumber);
}

public static void subscribeToTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String topicArn, String protocol, String endpoint) { 
    SubscribeRequest subscribe = new SubscribeRequest(topicArn, protocol, endpoint);
    SubscribeResult subscribeResult = snsClient.subscribe(subscribe);
    System.out.println("Subscribe request: " + 
            snsClient.getCachedResponseMetadata(subscribe));
    System.out.println("Subscribe result: " + subscribeResult);
}
```

The rest of your code seems fine.